# Update Foreign Key Object in EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have following Models:

```
public class DivorceCases
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  public string case_id { get; set; }
  public string archived { get; set; }
  public virtual Plaintiff p { get; set; }
}

public class Plaintiff{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am having a ModelView of DivorceCases for editing and in controller, I am using:

```
DivorceCases dcold = db.DivorceCase.Where(x => x.case_id == dc.case_id).Include(x => x.p).SingleOrDefault();
            dcold.p = dc.p;
            db.Entry(dcold).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

When I update, instead of Updating the existing entry in Plaintiffs table, the EF6 inserts a new record in Plaintiffs table and updates the foreign key reference for this new record in DivorceCases table. What am I doing wrong? How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Did you show the entire classes? I think this may have to do with initialization code in constructors.

Comment: @GertArnold no sir it isn't entire class. Actually for my case, I have got the solution which I have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution after repeated debugging and hit and trials.

First of all I made a DBContextExtension Class like this:

```
public static T Modify<T>(this T t,T tnew)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name != "id" && (property.PropertyType==typeof(string) || property.PropertyType==typeof(DateTime)))
            {
                if (property.GetValue(tnew) != null)
                property.SetValue(t, property.GetValue(tnew));
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Then for each foreign key referenced object, I called this Extension method and got 100% success.

```
DivorceCases dcold = db.DivorceCase.Where(x => x.case_id == dc.case_id).Include(x => x.p).SingleOrDefault();
            dcold = dcold.Modify(dc);
            dcold.p = dcold.p.Modify(dc.p);
            dcold.d = dcold.d.Modify(dc.d);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking your attached case entity to link to an item that is *not* attached to the context.

Try to attach **dc.p** first or simply change the plaintiff id on the case instead of changing object.

Comment: could you please elborate sir. i did not get your words.

Comment: db.Plaintiff.Attach(dc.p);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `dc.p` to `dcold.p` assign the properties of `dc.p` to `dcold.p`'s  properties then call `SaveChanges();` . you don't need  `db.Entry(dcold).State = EntityState.Modified;` entity framework will update your data instead of creating new entry. Try the following code-

```
    DivorceCases dcold = db.DivorceCase.Where(x => x.case_id == dc.case_id)
            .Include(x => x.p).SingleOrDefault();
            dcold.p.name = dc.p.name;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this before your db.SaveChanges() call..

```
 db.p=db.Plaintiff.Where(x=>x.id==db.p.id);
```

Not sure if that'll work here.  My database structure is slightly different.  I'm storing foreign key ids in the linking table... I use that value passed in... (...Where(x=>x.id==PlaintiffID)